# What is best practice on creating an index?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index, index-tuning, mysql-workbench

what is the best practice on creating an index?

example 1:

createdd_at_indx (created_at)

updated_at_indx (updated_at)

OR

example 2:

date_indx (created_at, updated_at)

Comment: Entirely depends on the purpose. [how mysql uses indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html), [use the index luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/), [Rick's ROT for indexing](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots#indexing)

Comment: Remember - server can use only one index for one table instance in the query. But for 2 table copies it may use either the same or different indices.

Comment: And my [_Index Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .

Comment: Those columns smell like columns that you would test with a range?

Comment: I see lots of tables containing `created_at` and `updated_at`, but I wonder if users ever touch those columns??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference, [Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

It depends on the query used.

For example the index `date_indx (created_at, updated_at)` will be used in the in the following queries :

```
SELECT yt.* FROM your_table yt 
 WHERE created_at='???????';

SELECT yt.* FROM your_table yt 
 WHERE created_at='???????' 
   AND updated_at='???????';

SELECT yt.* FROM your_table yt 
 WHERE created_at='???????' 
  AND (updated_at='???????' 
       OR updated_at='???????');

SELECT yt.* FROM your_table yt 
 WHERE created_at='???????' 
   AND updated_at >='???????' 
   AND updated_at < '???????';
```

And will not be used on the following queries:

```
SELECT yt.* FROM your_table yt 
 WHERE updated_at='???????';

SELECT yt.* FROM your_table yt 
 WHERE created_at='???????' 
    OR updated_at='???????';
```

Comment: thank you really appreciate it !

Answer (score 1):

*The best practice for making indexes is to start with the queries*.  That is, you cannot do a "good" job at building indexes before that.

Put multiple columns in the index for cases where

- The *first* column(s) are tested with `=` (or `IS NULL`) (if any)
- Then an `IN`-tested column (if any)
- Then a range-tested column (`>`, `BETWEEN`, `LIKE 'foo%'`, etc) (if any)

It is [mostly] useless to have two range-tested in an index -- the first might get used; the rest ignored.

In *some* cases, the Optimizer will prefer to ignore the `WHERE` and go for the `GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY`.

It is OK to have multiple indexes -- but [usually] only one will be used per `SELECT`.  Note:  subqueries, derived tables, and Unioned queries are each separately optimized.

More: [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: thanks for the input !

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application and your queries.
Generically speaking, if you have the same query using both Created_At and Updated_At in the Where clause, go ahead with option 2.
If there are separate queries using both separately, create separate indexes.

Comment: thank you so much !